# double integration

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to evaluate a double integral, but the limits of one integral is a function of the second. Like this

```
A[(b_)?NumberQ] := 
  Pi - 2*b*g*
    NIntegrate[
     1/Sqrt[g^2 - b^2*g^2*y^2 - 4*y^12 + 4*y^6], {y, 0, 
      Solve[g^2 - b^2*g^2*y^2 - 4*y^12 + 4*y^6 == 0, y, Reals][[2]] - 
       0.00001}]; 
NIntegrate[2*(1 - Cos[A[b]])*b, {b, 0, 100000}]
```

The upper limit of the first integral is an polynomial equation that depends on `b` and the second integral is in `b` for `g = Sqrt[0.1]`, I have the value `5.3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
g = 10;
A[(b_)?NumberQ] := Pi - 2*b*g* NIntegrate[1/Sqrt[g^2 - b^2*g^2*y^2 - 4*y^12 + 4*y^6], 
                   {y, 0, Evaluate[y /. N@(Solve[g^2 - b^2*g^2*y^2 - 4*y^12 + 4*y^6 == 0, y, 
                                                                   Reals][[2]])] - 0.00001}];

 NIntegrate[2*(1 - Cos[A[b]])*b, {b, 0, 100000}]

(* 1.66667*10^10 *)
```

**edit**

But beware that there is a problem in the interval {0,4} :

```
Plot[A[x], {x, 2, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: i change the value of g , and the result is the same. It is always 1.66667*10^10  for any value of g.
is there something wrong ?

Comment: what is N@(Solve)  ??

Comment: @LucasGLeiteFPollito, `f@x` is equivalent to `f[x]`. Look up prefix, infix and postfix notations.